# How to run Tcl code in Atom?

Tags: tcl, atom-editor

I started to write some Tcl Lines in Atom, but the Script package I use isn't able to run Tcl.

Does anybody know other packages, or plug ins to solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>Have you considered submitting a pull request for Tcl? Adding support for new languages is quite easy, all you have to do is edit [`grammars.coffee`](https://github.com/rgbkrk/atom-script/blob/master/lib/grammars.coffee).</del>

Support for Tcl was just merged into the `atom-script` package and should be part of the next release.

Otherwise, have a look at the [build](https://atom.io/packages/build) package plus the [build-tclsh](https://atom.io/packages/build-tclsh) provider. Alternatively, the package lets you specify a custom build configuration as JSON/CSON/YAML.